# Messages bar at the top showing contradictory messages

Tags: feature-request, notifications, global-inbox, notification-bar

I just signed up to the meta.stackoverflow.com and then I clicked the associate accounts link.

When I had copied over the profile, I noticed that I had two messages in my top bar. One of them was telling me to visit my profile page to fill it out, and the other was saying I had the badge for filling everything out.

I guess it would need some sort of system that can when some messages occur they can cancel out others(?).

I just thought I would put this one out there as the regulars on this site probably don't go through the new user process very often, although I understand it might be a lot of work for a not much reward.

Comment: Now you just get a litte blue indicator - no more banner for badges!

Comment: @rtpHarry I don't suppose this is still happening, but with global inbox notifications instead of the top bar, is it?

Comment: (Something is missing, it is incomprehensible, etc. near *"system that can"*.)